# Configure ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework: “No database provider has been configured for this DbContext”

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to inject a simple connection string in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project.

appsettings.json:

```json
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxx;User Id=frontend;Password=xxx;"
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<DB>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));
```

DbContext:

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DB() { }

    public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItemList { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public class MenuItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    DB _context;
    public MenuItemsController(DB context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var ddd = _context.MenuItemList.ToList();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I get following error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

The connection string is read correctly from the appsettings file, am I missing something? I have read other posts where people just configure the connection part in the DB context but I would prefer to do it this way with injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two constructors on your database context type `DB`:

```
public DB(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) { }
public DB() { }
```

So when the dependency injection container is attempting to resolve the database context, it looks at those constructors and tries to determine which constructor to use the create the object.

First, it will look at the one expecting a `DbContextOptions<DbContext>` argument. Usually, the `DbContextOptions` are automatically registered as part of the `AddDbContext<T>()` call. However, the types that are registered are `DbContextOptions` (non-generic) and `DbContextOptions<T>`.

So in your case, for a database context `DB`, only the types `DbContextOptions` and `DbContextOptions<DB>` are registered.

So the dependency injection container is not able to resolve `DbContextOptions<DbContext>` and as such cannot use that constructor. So it will use the next constructor which happens to be the empty constructor. Since the empty constructor does not support any configuration, the database context will be unconfigured and you will receive that error when attempting to use it.

The solution is pretty simple: Adjust the `DbContextOptions<>` type in that constructor. You can either use `DbContextOptions` or `DbContextOptions<DB>`. The latter is generally preferred since it allows you to have multiple database contexts in the same application but if you just have one, then you can also just use the former. I would also recommend you to remove the empty constructor to make sure that it won’t be used accidentally:

```
public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options)
    : base(options)
{ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor accepting a `DbContextOptions` is wrong. You need one that accepts one for your specific `DbContext`. So instead of:

```
public DB(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

Use:

```
public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options) : base(options) { }
```

Comment: Your totally right, thanks. Your two guys with same answer dont know how to mark both as answered.

Comment: No problem, poke gives a better explanation of what went wrong.